# title in excel export in angular datatable is not working

Tags: angularjs, export-to-excel, angular-datatables

I am using angular data table to show my data in frontend app. I want to export the data table in excel and pdf. In pdf the title is working fine but in excel the titile is not showed up.

Here is my code. The title will come from api. in pdf it's working as expected but not in excel export.

```
vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise(function() {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        defer.resolve(records);
        return defer.promise;
    })
    .withDOM('<"mb15"B>lfrtip')
    .withPaginationType('full_numbers').withBootstrap().withLanguage({
        'sSearch': '<b>Filter: </b>',
        'sSearchPlaceholder': 'Search...'
    }).withOption('scrollX', '100%')
    .withButtons([
        {
            extend: 'excel',
            text: 'Excel',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11] //we don't want the first 'control' column
            },
            className: 'btn btn-info mr5',
            filename: 'bill_' + now,
            title: all_billings[0].billing_header

        },
        {
            extend: 'pdf',
            text: 'PDF',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11] //we don't want the first 'control' column
            },
            className: 'btn btn-info buttons-csv buttons-html5',
            filename: 'bill_' + now,
            orientation: 'landscape',
            title: all_billings[0].billing_header
        }
    ]);
```